# In Entity Framework 6, how to receive an entity as well as associated entities from a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

Assume I have the following (the real case in more complex) CLR objects:

```
class Student {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Grade> Grades {get;set;}
}

class Grade {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Grade {get;set;}
    public string Course {get;set;}      

    public virtual Student Student {get;set;}
    public int StudentId {get;set;}
}
```

And the following stored procedure:

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM Students AS S 
  INNER JOIN Grades AS G ON S.Id = G.StudentId
```

How do I execute the query from Entity Framework such that the resulting value will be a collection of `Students` with their `Grades` collections filled?

Obviously this could be achieved directly by using Entity Framework entities but the actual case is much more complex and the resulting EF query takes over 100 times more time than a stored procedure which achieves the same query. My only issue is how to receive the data when it returns

Answer (score 0):

Just curious: is the stored proc imported in your EF-DbContext?
The result of this stored proc will be a complex result, in this case an object containing both the properties of the Student (Id, Age and Name) as well as the properties of the Grade (Id, Grade, Course, StudentId).
For each Grade, you will receive a separate record from the stored proc, which is mapped to the complex result i.e. object.

In order to get the list of Students with each having their own Grades-Collection, group the result object, e.g.

```
query = StoredProcResults.GroupBy(res => res.StudentId);
```

Comment: Your answer assumed I already have a StoredProcResults collection comprised of strongly typed entities. But your missing the actual question. HOW do I get the results of a stored procedure to populate my .net entities?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, Guy.Import the stored proc in you EF model: right click on the designer, choose 'Add' and under

Comment: ... In order to import the stored proc in your EF model: open the EF model designer, right click on the designer, choose 'Update Model from database', in the tab 'Add' under 'Stored Procedures' select your stored proc; ensure that 'Import selected stored procedures and functions into the entity model' is checked, click Finish and then Save these changes. The save will perform the actual import.

Comment: Assume that what I wrote is my stored procedure

Comment: In that case, you can use ObjectResult<TElement> ExecuteStoreQuery<TElement>(string commandText, params object[] parameters) on the ObjectContext of your DbContext (((IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).ObjectContext). The commandText is the name of you stored proc, the params collection contains any params of your stored proc. The TElement is a C# object you need in order to map the results to.

Comment: First, thanks for your continued assistance. The problem here is the mapping into the child collection (Grades). what you are proposing, or alternatively calling DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<Student>(...sql...) simply doesnt populate the Grades collection. Can you give me a code example using the classes i have mentioned? (changes to the sql syntax, if needed, are welcome)

Comment: Hi Guy, I got this working: var results = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<SPResult>("proc_GetStudents").ToList(); var group = results.GroupBy(res => res.Id); where the SPResult object has the following properties: Id (of the student), Age, Name, Grade and Course. It's not exactly a Student object with a Collection of Grade objects, but the structure is the same, so with some mapping you're done.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this work around if I won't be able to find a way to map directly into my existing objects